# Google Sheets Sumif Formula Parse Error

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I’m trying to enter a simple `=sumif` formula and keep getting the dreaded formula parse error or result is 0

Reading other responses, I did try replacing `,` with `;` and still the same error

In trying to tally headcount if RSVP = `Y`, I’ve tried:

`=sumif(A1:A30,Y,B1:B30)` result is 0

`=sumif(A1:A30,”Y”,B1:B30)` result is formula parse error

`=sumif(A1:A30;Y;B1:B30)` result is 0 and when I check formula again, the `;` are changed to `,`

`=sumif(A1:A30;”Y”;B1:B30)` result is a formula parse error and the `;` remain `,`

I’ve formatted the responses column so `Y` is plain text and have also tried automatic formatting, no change in results.

I feel like I’m missing something obvious but unsure what.  Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 3):

instead of **`” ”`** you need to use **`" "`**

try: **`=SUMIF(A1:A30, "Y", B1:B30)`**

[image]

regarding **`American ,`** vs. **`European ;`**...

you are using American version of syntax so all **`;`** are auto-converted to **`,`**

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I just enter quotes via keyboard on my iPhone and iPad.  I had to copy your quote marks to get the formula to work.  Any idea how to enter the appropriate quote marks directly?  Thanks again!!

Comment: @JCP https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYbAM.png (press and hold to bring up character selection)